# Aquire a "network" lock that locks wifi when it's used, but doesn't when 3G is used?

Tags: android, android-wifi, powermanager, android-powermanager

Currently I have this in my code:

```
WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock = ((WifiManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))
    .createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "MyWifiLock");
wifiLock.aquire();
```

However my app uses "any" type of network. When there's no Wifi connection it automatically uses 3G data. Is there a way to optimize this code somehow so that it only locks WiFi if it's actually being used? The only way I can think of doing it is to change the above code to something like:

```
PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext())
    .edit()
    .putBoolean(PREF_WIFI_LOCK_NEEDED, true)
    .apply();
```

and creating some NetworkStateReceiver that listens to WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION and/or ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts and aquire/release the lock somehow (and probably saving the lock to a static member of my Application?)

Is there a recommended way to do this?